# Roasting a frozen Creole Pork Leg?

Tags: pork, roast

I have a cookbook from Panama and the directions are sometimes missing or can be very broad. I'm a new cook so I need exact directions. I've tried Googling too but can't seem to find other recipes that ask to freeze the pork.

Is there a reason it says 24 hours, like it's only partially frozen in 24? And after the 24 hours, I put it on the oven frozen for 2 1/2 hours? Or do you defrost it? Do you cover it?

Preparation:
Place all the ingredients except the meat in a bowl and crush well.
Wash the meat and dry it well. Make superficial cuts with a sharp knife.
Cover the meat with the mixture of ground ingredients and place in the freezer for 24 hours.
Preheat the oven to 350 F and roast the meat for 2 1/2 hours until well cooked.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no doubt in my mind that this is a serious case of "lost in translation". Where it states to place in the freezer for 24 hours I genuinely believe it means the fridge. Never have I heard of freezing meat as a preparation method for cooking joints. Especially if the intended cooking time is only 2 1/2 hours, it'll still be raw in the middle.